# Como se cuando, por ejemplo mi player cae al vacio, para poder dar asi mi juego como terminado?

Tags: unity3d, unity

Tengo un plano largo en mi juego y una esfera(es mi player), puede caer al vacio como podria saber que ya cayo al vacio para poder dar asi el juego como terminado?
Ayuda por favor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias crear una barra "invisible" que detecte si la esfera cayo al vacio.
Por ejemplo, si tienes una barra como "base" en donde el player camine, simplemente pon una barra abajo de esa misma y entonces cuando la esfera choque con dicha barra que imprima por pantalla "Game Over" o algo por el estilo